# typing of multi-argument function in Dart

Tags: dart, types

Known that we can do `typedef EventHandler<T> = void Function(T arg);` in dart, how could we type any functions with some amount of params like:

```dart
typedef EventHandler<T0, T1> = void Function(T0 arg0, T1 arg1);
```

this works though, but I want to save such different callbacks in a generic list:

```dart
class Event<...T extends Objects?> {
  final List<EventHandler<...T> _handlers = [];

  // and maybe generic argument list for different callbacks
  //   e.g. (String, int) -> void
  void emit(T[] ...args) {
    for (var callback in _handlers) {
      callback(...args);
    }
  }
}
```

What works now allows me to do sth like:

```dart
// place all arguments in one class instance,
// and use the Class as generic T.
final onSituation = Event<SomeEventArg>();
```

rather than:

```dart
final onSituation = Event<String, int>();
// ...
onSituation.addCallback((str, index) {});
onSituation.emit("hello", 114514);
```

p.s. this is available in TS with

```js
type EventHandler<T extends any[]> = (...args: T) => void
```